# Selling an electronic cigarette to a minor

Tags: sin, transactions, minor-katan-child, tobacco-cig-smoking

Is it a sin to sell [an electronic cigarette](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electronic_cigarette) it to a minor?

Please cite sources.

Comment: For you to get a good-quality answer, your question should include all relevant information you know about. For instance the answer will depend on whether these devices are harmful to the health. We are not vape specialists here :-> Would you mind giving a bit more information on the health impact of vapes? Also is it against the law to vape for a minor? What are other issues that might occur? Getting a minor in the habit of "smoking/vaping"? Do these things create dependency?

Comment: Are we referring to a minor as defined by halacha? Israeli law? The State of Massachusetts?

Answer (score 2):

Since it is a felony to sell tobacco products or electronic cigarettes to minors in most civilized countries, it would be forbidden to do this based on the principle of "dina d'malchuta dina". You could end up in jail for doing something like this, I hope you don't plan on doing this.

Answer (score 1):

They are bad for your health and a minor may not fully understand this. This is why there are laws against selling certain items to minors. That being the case I would think this could fit under the sun of "placing a stumbling block in front of the blind".